# Java - space between message

Tags: java

Hey guys I have a simple problem that I'm blanking on. All I need to do is print out the distance between the message and the asteriks:

[image]

which should look like:

[image]

this is my code:

```
if(msg.length() < 54) 
  {
   for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++)
   {
       System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.print("\n***");


    int length=msg.length();
    int whiteSpace = (54 - (msg.length())/2);


    System.out.print(msg);


    for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("");
    }
    System.out.print("***");


    for (int x = 0; x<=whiteSpace; x++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }


    System.out.print("\n");

    for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
```

}

If you guys could help me that would be great.

Comment: `System.out.print("");` Start there

Comment: You could cheat and use something like `String result = String.format("%s%" + spacing + "s%s%" + spacing + "s", "***", " ", msg, "***");` where `spacing` is the amount of leading and trailing space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there will be problem with the border if you not setting the border too, you know if the message.length is even the star will not look pretty.
try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String msg = "Hello Bebeb";
    int border=60;
    if(msg.length()%2 ==0){
        border+=1;
    }
    if (msg.length() < 54) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= border; x++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n***");

        int length = msg.length();
        int whiteSpace = ((54 - (msg.length())) / 2);


        for (int x = 0; x <= whiteSpace; x++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print(msg);

        for (int x = 0; x <= whiteSpace; x++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("***");

        for (int x = 0; x <= whiteSpace; x++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print("\n");

        for (int x = 0; x <= border; x++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! The border was the problem I was having in the end.